# FreeRTOS Project Setup with error: expected ')' before string constant

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am starting a new project on a STM32L476 Nucleo board and planned to use FreeRTOS.

My initial project structure:

main.c

```
#include "project.h"

int main(void)
{
  /* Configure the system clock */
  Clock_Config();

  /* Configure IOs */
  GPIO_Config();

  /* FreeRTOS Stuff */

  NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(3);

  vTaskStartScheduler();

  /* Should never get here! */
  while (1){}
}
```

project.h

```
#ifndef PROJECT_H_
#define PROJECT_H_

/* MPU Files */
#include "stm32l4xx.h"
/* Project Files */
#include "gpio.h"
#include "clock.h"
/* FreeRTOS */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "task.h"

#define TASKPRIO_STD            ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1 )
#define TICK_TASK_PERIOD_MS     pdMS_TO_TICKS( 500 )

#endif /* PROJECT_H_ */
```

project.c

```
#include "project.h"

static void vSerialTask( void * pvParameters );

xTaskCreate( vSerialTask, "I2C", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, TASKPRIO_STD, NULL);

static void vSerialTask( void *pvParameters ){

   for( ;; )
   {

   }
}
```

I get a syntax error with this structure in xTaskCreate line: expected ')' before string constant

If I move xTaskCreate to my main.c and leave the task itself in my project.c (also have to delete static in this case) my project compiles successfully.

What is the problem here? I already saw working projects where xTaskCreate is not done within main.c so can't imagine this is the real problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the function outside another function and it is exactly what you try to do.

You can only call functions from another functions. The first function executed is `main`